# How do I resolve Activity (for callback binding)?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I a not an experienced app developer. please forgive me for this question.
I am trying to add firebase OTP into my app.
I got stuck at

```
 PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber("number")       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

what is  `.setActivity(this)`?  What I am supposed to do here?? This is the full code link: https://www.codepile.net/pile/MR8YdA3k

and error screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`public PhoneAuthOptions.Builder setActivity (Activity activity)`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#public-phoneauthoptions.builder-setactivity-activity-activity)

Sets the Activity to which the `callbacks are scoped`, and with which app verification will be completed.

For **Activity**

```
.setActivity(this)
```

For **Fragment**

```
.setActivity(getActivity())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber("number")       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(getActivity())                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

Listen this callback in the fragment's activity.

Answer (score 1):

The class named 'Phone_F' should be an activity, not a fragment. That means the 'Phone_F' class should extend an activity instead of a fragment. Follow [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/phone-number-verification-using-firebase-in-android/) for details. And let me know if I could be any more help. Happy coding.