# Type mismatched : Activity (for callback binding)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add firebase phone OTP verification in a fragment and I got stuck at .setActivity(...)  [image: 1]

when in an activity we use "this", but in a fragment what to use?

```
private fun sendVerificationcode(number: String) {
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
        .setPhoneNumber(number)       // Phone number to verify
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
        .setCallbacks(mCallBacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
```

I also referred to [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563753/how-do-i-resolve-activity-for-callback-binding)but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of one in fragment.

```
requireActivity() //for fragment
getActivity() as Activity // in Kotlin
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call to `getActivity()` is returning an optional, which by definition can be null.  The `.setActivity()` method does not allow null values to be passed in.  Validate `getActivity()` doesn't return null before you proceed.

```
getActivity().let{ activity -> 
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
    .setPhoneNumber(number)       // Phone number to verify
    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
    .setActivity(activity)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
    .setCallbacks(mCallBacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
```